# how to change search permalink in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have custom search page, that have permalink http://mywebsite.com/custom-search/

What should I do to pass the search keyword as a parameter, like this: http://mywebsite.com/custom-search/keyword

I get error 404 page. Or may be there a way to change standard permalink /search/ to /custom-search/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just changed search base with function

```
function vital_custom_search_base() {
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->search_base = 'custom-search';
}

add_action( 'init', 'vital_custom_search_base' );
```

function only works after resave in settings > permalinks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `rewrite endpoints`
A sample code :

```
/*!
 * URL rewrite
 */
function my_custom_rewrite_rules() {
    $page_id = 123;
    $page_path = get_page_uri( $page_id );

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'keyword', EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_rule('^'. $page_path .'/(.*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=' . $page_id . '&keyword=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

and then add it as a `query_var`

```
function my_custom_query_vars($vars) {      
    if( isset( $_GET['keyword'] ) && !empty( $_GET['keyword'] ) ) {
        $vars[] = 'keyword';
    }

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars', 10, 1 );
```

you will be able to retrieve the value of the passed keyword via `get_query_var("keyword")`
hope it helps

**Note :** You must update your permalinks structure or use `flush_rewrite_rules();` after adding these codes

Comment: may I can just change search base? tried to change var $search_base = 'search'; to custom-search in class-wp-rewrite, but nothing happens. Search anyway works with /search/ base...

Comment: @user3514052 You must update permalink structure, each time you update it, create a page with `search` slug and update permalink structure , it should do it